# Infinite vertical sliding effect of divs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I want to have a gallery where the divs will slide up and down.
Now I'm not sure if this is the right approach because  this is obviously terrible code, but
if there's a proper way of doing this please point me to the right direction..
my fiddle
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/deadbysunrise/5m24e/1/)

```
$(function () {
    grid_move();

    function grid_move() {
        $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").animate({
            bottom: "-=400"
        },
        3000,
            "linear",

        function () {
            grid_move();
        });
    }
});
```

That I coded slides down but disappears now what I wanna do is that all the 5 divs under colum1 will repeat the animation, like a carousel the last div will be followed by the first and so on,

(By the way, I don't like plugins i want to do this myself :)
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what about the page scroll, do you find this a nice efx? I really don't understand how you expect that gallery to work. Please be more specific!

Comment: yes it is i just want the #column1 to repeat the animation that i did just like a carousel

Comment: ok, but why is all the document scrollable? should not the gallery be height 100% or something that would fix inside a screen height?

Comment: i dont know how can i make the 5(#one,#two...) divs to repeat the animation, i want the last div(#five) to be followed by (#one)div over and over but mine disappears coz of the overflowhidden now im trying to do an infinite loop by calling the function again but that it isnt working

Comment: http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/examples/vertical.html <br> i wanted to be exactly like this, i wanted to show the previous divs after the last 1

Comment: You need to calculate when will an element slide out of the container, and as soon as it's not into view, reposition it in the beginning of the queue.